# Importing NULL as NULL in SQL Server Import and Export Wizard

Tags: sql-server, null, ssms, sql-server-2016

I have a table test as follows :

```
id  name  
--------
1   abc  
2   jkl  
3   def  
4   NULL  
5   PQR
```

I want to copy the same data to somewhere else So I prepare one text file as

```
id  name  
--------
 1  abc  
 2  jkl  
 3  def  
 4  NULL(this has come automatically when copying the data with 'Copy with  Headers' option in SSMS)  
 5  PQR
```

When I import this file using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard taking the Data Source as 'Flat File Source' and Destination as 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0' the data import is done as fine but my issue is for ID 4 the name is coming as 'NULL'(String) in the new table.

I want it to be `NULL` (SQL Server `NULL`) not as String 'NULL'.

Comment: If you want `NULL`, don't have the literal word "NULL" in your text file. `NULL` in a text file would be the omission of a value. `'NULL'` and `NULL` are not the same.